# MySQL: Error Code 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint. I have no duplicate Primary keys & all data types match

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-workbench

I'm a student and I've probably been struggling with this issue for about a few hours now, checking the MySQL syntax online assistance, other stackoverflow questions, and my textbook. I've been tweaking my code repeatedly and I'm completely stumped.

I've been trying to use the Forward Engineer feature on MySQL, but on the table titled 'LabT3' I keep getting the 1215 error message: Cannot add foreign key constraint. I will post the code below. As I said in the title, I've checked to make sure I don't have duplicate Primary Keys, and the data types on all my attributes match from table to table. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Here's the code. Any input would be greatly appreciated:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Lab 2
-- Amber Lewis
-- Entity-Relationship Diagram for sample Clinic

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram
--
-- Lab 2
-- Amber Lewis
-- Entity-Relationship Diagram for sample Clinic
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`DoctorT2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`DoctorT2` (
  `DoctorID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `DoctorName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Dept` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DoctorID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`PatientT1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`PatientT1` (
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Age` INT NULL,
  `Weight` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `Gender` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `PhoneNo` INT NULL,
  `Disease` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `DoctorID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`, `DoctorID`),
  INDEX `fk_Patient - T1_Doctor - T2_idx` (`DoctorID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Patient - T1_Doctor - T2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DoctorID`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`DoctorT2` (`DoctorID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`OutpatientT5`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`OutpatientT5` (
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `LabNo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`, `Date`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`RoomT6`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`RoomT6` (
  `RoomNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `RoomType` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `Status` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RoomNo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`InpatientT4`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`InpatientT4` (
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `RoomNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `DateOfAdm` DATE NOT NULL,
  `DateOfDis` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Advance` INT NOT NULL,
  `LabNo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`, `RoomNo`, `DateOfAdm`),
  INDEX `fk_InpatientT4_RoomT61_idx` (`RoomNo` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_InpatientT4_RoomT61`
    FOREIGN KEY (`RoomNo`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`RoomT6` (`RoomNo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`LabT3`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`LabT3` (
  `LabNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `Weight` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `DoctorID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Category` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `PatientType` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LabNo`, `PID`),
  INDEX `fk_LabT3_DoctorT2_idx` (`DoctorID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_LabT3_OutpatientT5_idx` (`PID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_LabT3_DoctorID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DoctorID`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`DoctorT2` (`DoctorID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_LabT3_PID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PID`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`OutpatientT5` (`PID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_LabT3_InpatientT41`
    FOREIGN KEY (`LabNo`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`InpatientT4` (`LabNo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`BillT7`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`BillT7` (
  `BillNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `PatientType` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `DoctorCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `MedicineCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `RoomCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `OperationCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `NursingCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `LOS` INT NOT NULL,
  `Advance` INT NOT NULL,
  `HealthCard` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Lab Charge` INT NOT NULL,
  `Bill` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BillNo`, `PID`),
  INDEX `fk_BillT7_OutpatientT51_idx` (`PID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_BillT7_OutpatientT51`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PID`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`OutpatientT5` (`PID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here by I have changed the table Lab3 and InpatientT4.

Lab3 is main table with primary key LabNo,so foreign key relation in InpatientT4 to be added and removed the foreign key refernce in Lab3.

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Lab 2
-- Amber Lewis
-- Entity-Relationship Diagram for sample Clinic

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram
--
-- Lab 2
-- Amber Lewis
-- Entity-Relationship Diagram for sample Clinic
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`DoctorT2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`DoctorT2` (
  `DoctorID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `DoctorName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Dept` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DoctorID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`PatientT1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`PatientT1` (
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Age` INT NULL,
  `Weight` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `Gender` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `PhoneNo` INT NULL,
  `Disease` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `DoctorID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`, `DoctorID`),
  INDEX `fk_Patient - T1_Doctor - T2_idx` (`DoctorID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Patient - T1_Doctor - T2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DoctorID`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`DoctorT2` (`DoctorID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`OutpatientT5`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`OutpatientT5` (
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `LabNo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`, `Date`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`RoomT6`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`RoomT6` (
  `RoomNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `RoomType` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `Status` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RoomNo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`LabT3`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`LabT3` (
  `LabNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `Weight` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `DoctorID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Category` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `PatientType` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LabNo`, `PID`),
  INDEX `fk_LabT3_DoctorT2_idx` (`DoctorID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_LabT3_OutpatientT5_idx` (`PID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_LabT3_DoctorID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DoctorID`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`DoctorT2` (`DoctorID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_LabT3_PID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PID`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`OutpatientT5` (`PID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`InpatientT4`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`InpatientT4` (
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `RoomNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `DateOfAdm` DATE NOT NULL,
  `DateOfDis` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Advance` INT NOT NULL,
  `LabNo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`, `RoomNo`, `DateOfAdm`),
  INDEX `fk_InpatientT4_RoomT61_idx` (`RoomNo` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_InpatientT4_RoomT61`
    FOREIGN KEY (`RoomNo`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`RoomT6` (`RoomNo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_LabT3_InpatientT41`
    FOREIGN KEY (`LabNo`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`LabT3` (`LabNo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`BillT7`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`BillT7` (
  `BillNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `PID` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `PatientType` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `DoctorCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `MedicineCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `RoomCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `OperationCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `NursingCharge` INT NOT NULL,
  `LOS` INT NOT NULL,
  `Advance` INT NOT NULL,
  `HealthCard` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Lab Charge` INT NOT NULL,
  `Bill` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BillNo`, `PID`),
  INDEX `fk_BillT7_OutpatientT51_idx` (`PID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_BillT7_OutpatientT51`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PID`)
    REFERENCES `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`OutpatientT5` (`PID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to debug this is to remove each FK statement until the script runs. That will tell you exactly which FK is the problem. This a great technique to debug DDL scripts; keep taking things out until it works so you find the exact error cause.

When doing that, you'll probably find that `fk_LabT3_InpatientT41` is incorrect. You are creating a foreign key to a non-key field in `Amber's_Clinic_ER_Diagram`.`InpatientT4` (`LabNo`).

I think you have that FK statement on the wrong table. You probably want the FK to point to LabT3, not InpatientT4.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I've stared at this for so long that my brain just went to mush. Now that I'm reading this it's embarrassingly clear that a Foreign key denotes a value being used as a primary key in another table. You've just ended hours of self-torment.